# Select indices where value np.nonzero() and ~np.isnan()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to select only those indices where value is different than 'Nan' and 0

#### Create Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,3,0,2],
                   'B':[0,1,1,2]})

df = np.asarray(df)
```

#### Unfortunately below code does not work

```
df[np.nonzero(df) & ~np.isnan(df)]
```

#### Expected result

```
array(3,1,1,2,2)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to 1d array by [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and then for non `0` values compare by `!= 0`:

```
a = np.ravel(df.to_numpy())
a = a[(a != 0) & ~np.isnan(a)]
print (a)
[3. 1. 1. 2. 2.]
```

Like mentioned @sammywemmy, thank you, here `np.ravel` is not necessary:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
a = a[(a != 0) & ~np.isnan(a)]
print (a)
[3. 1. 1. 2. 2.]
```

You cannot compare by [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), because it return indices instead mask:

> Return the indices of the elements that are non-zero.

Comment: dont think u need to ravel; it seems numpy flattens it out at the end ...```df[~(np.isnan(df)) & (df!=0)]```

Comment: It works without ravel in my case. flatten() function is not necessary